# Possible to identify a quadratic polynomial using only $\sigma_0(f(x))$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratics, irreducible-polynomials, divisor-counting-function

You're given some integer-valued irreducible quadratic function $f(x):=ax^2+bx+c$ with positive lead coefficient $a$, but you don't know anything else about it. However, you're able to get the divisor count for as many values of $x$ as you'd like with $\sigma_0(f(x))$.

I'm curious whether it is possible to identify the specific function you've been given using *finitely* many of these divisor counts, but its usage is otherwise unrestricted. If it's relevant, assume the function meets the criteria to be able to yield primes.

It seems to me that whether this task is possible may end up depending on the infinitude of polynomial primes, but I worry I'm overlooking more obvious solutions, or properties that make it trivially impossible.

Comment: it's not like the be all end all but $f(1)$ being prime can tell us a lot.

Comment: Note that $\sigma_0(f(n))$ is odd if and only if $f(n)$ is square. And if $f(n)$ is square, $c$ must be a quadratic residue modulo $n$. Also note that $D+4f(n)$ is always square, where $D=b^2-4ac$. So if $f(n)$ is not always square, ($D\neq 0$), but $f(n)$ is square, this gives $|D|\ge 2n-1$.

Comment: and by polynomial remainder theorem we know that at most the value for $x=k$ is is the sum of the values at it's remainders in mod.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to work out an algorithm to derive residues and non-residues given a sufficient batch of data, so within a bounded set of possibilities, that works. The larger problem is that however many residues I work out, as I understand it, there are still infinitely many polynomials that share the same ones.

Comment: I can no longer edit my earlier comment, but it should be $|D|\ge 2\sqrt{f(n)}-1$ instead of $|D|\ge 2n-1$.

Comment: @Trevor but how many quadratics ?

Answer (score 1):

Lets try one out: $$f(x)=23x^2+3x+3$$ f(1) is prime so: $$\sigma_0(f(1))=2$$ to find out which primes are possibly f(1) we can test values that are 1 more than primes until we hit one with more than 2 (guaranteed to happen as $f(f(1)+1)$ has the same remainder on division by $f(1)$ as $f(1)$ does by polynomial remainder theorem). This at least gives us a minimum value of $a+b+c$. So lets try that:

$$\sigma_0(f(3))=4\\\sigma_0(f(4))=2\\\sigma_0(f(6))=4\\\sigma_0(f(8))=2\\\sigma_0(f(12))=4\\\sigma_0(f(14))=4\\\sigma_0(f(18))=4\\\sigma_0(f(20))=4\\\sigma_0(f(24))=4\\\sigma_0(f(30))=8\\\vdots$$

Okay not so useful it seems, f(2) can  be used showing $3a+b$ to be a difference of primes. This is only even ( the most likely case unless one of the primes is 2) if $a$ and $b$ are of the same parity. As 2 is even f(2) has the same parity as $c$. $f(4)$,$f(8)$, and $f(38)$ Also create differences in primes etc.

Comment: I swear one was suppose to have 8, but anyways $f(1)$, $f(2)$ being prime shows that none of the factors of any other member of the sequence can contain 2 unless one of $f(1),f(2)$ are 2, and f(0) shows that $c$ is a divisor of every c-th term.